# How to disable the current dates along with past date in showDatePicker?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to disable the current date in showDatePicker. I was able to disable the past date in the `showDatePicker` but i also want to disable the current date in `showDatePicker`

here is my code:

```
showDatePicker(
                                        context: context,
                                        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                        firstDate: DateTime.now()
                                            .subtract(Duration(days: 0)),
                                        lastDate: DateTime(2025),
                                        // selectableDayPredicate:
                                        //     _decideWhichDayToEnable,
                                      );
```

[image: the calender]

i have updated, user can still press the 24 but i want it to be disable..

Comment: initialDate:DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)),
 firstDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)),

Comment: @GursewakSingh base on the code, user can still select 24 in the calendar i dont want user to select the current day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intialDate property is the key here.

```
DateTime intialDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1));
showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: intialDate,
    initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
    firstDate: intialDate,
    lastDate: DateTime(2025));
```

This is the output am getting.
[image]

Comment: i am still able to select back.. i dont want user to select the current day..

Comment: I added my calendar widget screen to my answer, can you post what you are getting?

Comment: i have update it

Comment: sorry i get, the problem... thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I understand is that you have to set `Tomorrow` as the `firstDate` and `inialDate`. You just need to set those values like `DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1))`. I hope that will work.